# Android Full Control over BackupAgent

Tags: android, dropbox, android-backup-service

Before anyone points me to this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html, let me tell you that while I think is really great it also lacks some features I would like to have in my application.

I'd like to have a list of several backups (not just one in the cloud) and the option to backup/restore the file from another cloud storage (say Dropbox).

I don't know where the helpers store the files and how (if I can) restore from another location.

The guide its not very clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

The helpers don't store the files.  Helpers provide backup data to the BackupManager service and it talks to registered transports.  It's up to the transport to decide what it wants to do for multiple devices and backups.

Use the bmgr tool to select the local transport and run backups and restores - this is the best way to understand how the system works.

Remember that the data a BackupAgent produces is completely opaque.  You may be able to structure your data such that you are always merging new backup data in and deciding what to do with it when you restore.